# how to do parameter binding of a DataView Parameter with Value of a drop down list ?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, xslt

I have a dataview webpart, which is a dashboard. the value of the dashboard is obtained through different algorithms which are coded in XSL.

I created a DataView parameter which is used as a variable in the algorithm.
My requirement is to give the value of the drop down selected to the this paramter. or rather how can i bind it with the drop down selected value.

---

DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="True" DataValueField="Financial_x0020_Year" DataTextField="Financial_x0020_Year" DataSourceID="spdatasource1">

---

is the code generated for a dadropdown list !!

in the parameter binding i try doing the below;

---

ParameterBinding Name="Paramtervariable" Location="None" DefaultValue="DropDownList1.SelectedValue

---

Am i wrong in the syntax ?
Do i have to give anything in the Location ? by defualt it came as None - whats that Location stands for ?

KIndly help.

Comment: Can't see your code so how i can comment on your syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location should not be none

```
 <ParameterBinding Name="Param1" Location="Control(savebutton1)" DefaultValue="test"/>
```

Location should be

Location="Control(ControlID)"

DefaultValue = "Default Value in case Value from location is Null"

Comment: now i am stuck with mutiple entries in a dropdown list populated from a field in a custom list. i need only unique entries in the drop down workin on the same. thanks again for the help.

Comment: I don't think i would be able to help you much with the current approach you have taken only thing you can do is to apply a filter on your data source if that can help you in any way